# add_action don't updates theme layout when using values from the WordPress customizer

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, actions, theme-customizer

I am trying to control the order of the information displayed in the WooCommerce single product page via the customizer with a sortable control. The user can select if the different elements are displayed or not, and the order of them. This elements are the title, price, etc.

[image]

WooCommerce loads this information in the `content-single-product.php` template using the following code:

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">
    <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
</div>
```

`do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );` allows to remove and hook other functionalities in that theme.

So what I did is firtly to unhook all the actions via remove_action( `'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);`, which works fine.

In my functions.php retrieve the value of my sortable field with a default value (array):

```
$product_summary_elements = get_theme_mod( 'product_summary_layout', array(
    'woocommerce_template_single_title',
    'woocommerce_template_single_rating',
    'woocommerce_template_single_price',
    'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt',
    'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',
    'woocommerce_template_single_meta',
    'woocommerce_template_single_sharing'
    )
);
```

Finally, added the following code to hook those functions in the chosen order:

```
if ( ! empty( $product_summary_elements ) && is_array( $product_summary_elements ) ) {
    foreach ( $product_summary_elements as $element ) {
      add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',''.$element.'');
    }
}
```

**The problem:**
It doesn't update when I change the options in the customizer, transport is set to refresh. It does updates when I refresh the page on the browser.

***When I change the previous code to the following and include it in the theme file***, it updates without a problem:

```
if ( ! empty( $product_summary_elements ) && is_array( $product_summary_elements ) ) {
    foreach ( $product_summary_elements as $element ) {
      $element();
    }
}
```

The above code basically calls the functions that are hooked in a given order without the hook.

Why does this happen, is there a workaround?

Comment: `$element();` works because `$element` is a function — [example](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_template_single_title.html). Try re-add the actions right after you removed the default actions. And, are you sure the default actions were actually removed?

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ yes all the default actions are actually removed and the actions are added just after those are removed, in the functions.php file.

Comment: Could it be because of this: `''.$element.''` ? Looks like `'"'.$element.'"'`, but I'm not sure. (Please ignore the `init` thing, since the actions were removed.)

Comment: Hey @SallyCJ than you a lot! It was exactly that! If you answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hey @SallyCJ Sorry. I did it, and it worked, but I reversed the change to check back and now it is working. I really don't understand why. The only change I did is that I added another control to unhook the breadcrumbs and it is happening with the new control.


remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);

`// Unhook woocommerce breadcrumbs
if (get_theme_mod('unhook_breadcrumbs', true) == true) {
 add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
}`

Comment: When you reversed the change, did you wrap all the action *names* in single/double quotes as in `'action'` or `"action"`? If you only wrapped the `woocommerce_breadcrumb`, then maybe only that action that was actually re-added? :)

Comment: It is left as the original `''.$element.''` (two single quotes on each side).

Comment: Actually, ignore my previous comment (that I've deleted). But [this](http://codepad.org/NlXp11VF) might still be useful to you. :) And I'm not sure what's happening with your code, but I'd test it out if I could. ;) Or try *without* the quotes? `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', $element );`